# Find projection matrix to create zero-sum vector

Tags: r, matrix, projection

I have subspace of vectors `w` whose elements sum to 0.

I would like to find a projection matrix `Z` such that it projects any `x` vector onto the subspace w (i.e., a subspace where the vector sums to 0).

Is there an R function to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question did not specify how `w` is provided but if `w` is a matrix with full rank spanning the space w then

```
Z <- w %*% solve(crossprod(w), t(w))
```

If `w` has orthogonal columns then the above line reduces to:

```
Z <- tcrossprod(w)
```

Another possibility is to use the `pracma` package in which case `w` need not be of full rank:

```
library(pracma)
Z <- tcrossprod(orth(w))
```

If `w` were the space of **all** n-vectors that sum to zero then:

```
Z <- diag(n) - matrix(1, n, n) / n
```

**Note** Have revised after re-reading question.